# How can I create separate web directories for each application in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

For instance, I have two applications: 'frontend' and 'backend'. I'd like my /web directory to be set up so that '/web/frontend' serves the 'frontend' assets, and '/web/backend' serves the 'backend' assets without having to go modify all the image paths, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Symfony Documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_sub_modifying_the_project_web_root), doing this in each app's config.php should work [example is showing apps/backend/config/config.php]

```
sfConfig::add(array(
  'sf_web_dir'      => SF_ROOT_DIR.'/web/backend',
  'sf_upload_dir'   => SF_ROOT_DIR.'/web/backend'.sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir_name'),
));
```

For some reason, this method doesn't work. If you take a look at all the variables defined inside sfConfig, you'll notice that you have to change more than sf_web_dir and sf_upload_dir to get things working.

One option would be to manually override the all variables inside sfConfig that point to the web directory inside each app's config.php. To see a list of all the variables, try

```
<?php echo var_dump(sfConfig::getall()); ?>
```

Your other option (The way I've done it before) would be to do it in the Apache configuration. Your virtual host settings for backend would look something like

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName backend.dev
  DocumentRoot "PATH_TO_SYMFONY_PROJECT/web/backend"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Alias /sf /usr/local/lib/php/data/symfony/web/sf
  <Directory "/usr/local/lib/php/data/symfony/web/sf">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
  </Directory>
  <Directory "PATH_TO_SYMFONY_PROJECT/web/backend">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you will need to copy backend.php, backend_dev.php [ and possibly index.php if backend is your default enviroment ] to /web/backend, and in each one of those files, change

```
define('SF_ROOT_DIR',    realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..'));
```

to

```
define('SF_ROOT_DIR',    realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..'));
```

and you should be good. I prefer this method, but if you don't have virtual hosts setup, you might not have this option.

Comment: You probably already know this... Your symfony install might be somewhere other than "/usr/local/lib/php/data/symfony/web/sf"

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough response sjobe! I'll try it out and then mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for your help sjobe, I appreciate it.